# Question about the unbuffered I/O efficiency introduced in APUE 3th, 3.9

Tags: linux, io, programming

In Advanced Programming in Unix Environment 3th, 3.9, I/O Efficiency, I read about this:

> The file was read using the program shown in Figure 3.5, with standard
>   output redirected to /dev/null. The file system used for this test was
>   the Linux ext4 file system with 4,096-byte blocks. (The st_blksize
>   value, which we describe in Section 4.12, is 4,096.) This accounts for
>   the minimum in the system time occurring at the few timing
>   measurements starting around a BUFFSIZE of 4,096. **Increasing the
>   buffer size beyond this limit has little positive effect.**

My question is why "Increasing the buffer size beyond this limit has little positive effect"? I think increasing the buffer size will definitely reduce the user cpu time and system cpu time because of the reduce of number of loops so that the clock time will also be reduced to certain degrees, Isn't that so? And why?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56661/discussion-on-question-by-cong-question-about-the-unbuffered-i-o-efficiency-intr).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement "Increasing the buffer size beyond this limit has little positive effect" has no credibility.

The code as posted gives no indication whatsoever as to how many bytes are actually read then written in each loop iteration - via data *read from a pipe* - redirected `stdin`.  Given that the Linux `PIPE_BUF` value is normally 5120 bytes, the code probably reads and writes a handful of kilobytes with each loop iteration.

Once the buffer size grows larger than that, the number of bytes actually moved with each loop iterations doesn't change, so the buffer size is completely irrelevant.

Not only that, the methodology of the test is completely undocumented.  *How are the files passed to the process?* The book pages posted at https://www.dropbox.com/s/r67nacyrqb5ulww/apue_72-73.pdf?dl=0 don't specify - *at all*.  There's no way to duplicate the test *because we can't tell what the test was*.

Furthermore, perusal of the code at http://www.apuebook.com/src.3e.tar.gz indicates numerous problems - `read()` and `write()` are coded as if they return `int` instead of the correct `ssize_t`, signal handlers make calls to async-signal-***unsafe*** functions.

In other words, slipshod code and slipshod tests.

Comment: The use case is `./mycat <file >/dev/null` - no pipe is involved.

Comment: @SatoKatsura Based on what?  That's not documented in the pages you posted.  And it doesn't really matter - the code as posted doesn't account for how many bytes are read then written with each loop iteration, so the data is useless anyway.

Comment: _Based on what?_ - Based on the fact that that's the only setup that makes sense that involves `st_blksize`?

Comment: @SatoKatsura *the only setup that makes sense* [Again, no](https://www.google.com/search?q=useless+use+of+cat). And  [ext4 uses *de facto* variable-sized blocks](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout): "To reduce performance difficulties due to fragmentation, the block allocator tries very hard to keep each file's blocks within the same group, thereby reducing seek times... With the default block size of 4KiB, each group will contain 32,768 blocks, for a length of 128MiB." So the "4k" ext4 block size likely has little to nothing to do with the results posted. Still useless.

Comment: My point: if it were a pipe the book wouldn't have said anything about `st_blksize`.  In that sense, `./mycat <file >/dev/null` seems to be the only setup that makes sense _and_ matches the description in the book.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, if there is no redirection, fd in read(fd,buf,buffsize) is the return value of open(pathname,flags), while the pathname is just the file name.Will the statement "Increasing the buffer size beyond this limit has little positive effect" still be right?

Comment: @AndrewHenle That chapter is an _introduction_ to I/O. It claims that "if you're going to `read(2)` a file you'd better do it in chunks, the larger the better, but the returns will be diminishing if you go over the filesystem's block size". Does that hold if you consider pipes, sockets, threading, disk caching, multi-level buffering, and the kitchen sink? Nope. Should that informal benchmark be better explained? Sure. But all that is fine for an _introduction_. But at this point you're to fixed on name calling to consider where all this come from and where it's heading. For that, -1 from me.

Comment: @AndrewHenle On the other hand, +1 for pointing out that `read(2)` and `write(2)` return `ssize_t`. I'm pretty sure the first edition of the book predates `ssize_t`, but it's 2017 and the difference is not harmless. As for using signal-unsafe calls in signal handlers, I believe the author himself makes that very point, and he has an entire chapter dedicated to that. Sadly, said author passed away before the second edition of the book was out, and we're now at the 3rd edition.

Comment: @cong *....Will the statement "Increasing the buffer size beyond this limit has little positive effect" still be right?*  Probably not. In my experience (and I've benchmarked some serious high-performance filesystems for major customers that you've heard of...) that statement in general is just plain wrong. It can be true for certain implementations, but in general I'd say I/O performance tends to increase as buffer size goes up, to a point. But there are so many variables in IO performance there's no way such a generic statement can ever be termed true.

Comment: @cong IO benchmarks only apply to the system the test is run on, under the configuration and conditions that existed when the test was run. The test as documented provides none of that, so we don't know anything. And as I noted, we can't even tell if the `read()` operations are even using the entire buffer. You just can't tell with the information provided, so it has no specific applicability at all. Mass-market computers have fast CPUs and RAM (marketing) with the rest cheap/slow (profit). I can see newish commodity H/W behaving like that. HW with high-end MB and disks will be different.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, ok, thanks for you patience.